# How do I make the image to cover the size of the div while also keeping the aspect ratio so that i can still see the image in its entirety?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, aspect-ratio

Im trying to create a backround for the main section of my page. The size of the image is 640 x 480 and I want it to be the background for a container that is 1204 x 184. I know this question been asked before but none of the answers worked for me.

Question: How do I make the image to cover the size of the div while also keeping the aspect ratio so that i can still see the image in its entirety?.

p.s I added a my code but I do not have enough points yet to add pictures to my post.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-container{
    width: 98%;
    margin: auto;
    background: lightgray;
}

header{
    width:80%;
    height: 10%;
    background: grey;
    margin: auto
}
main{
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 80%;
    height:600px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   
 }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Layout practice</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="main-container">
       <header>
           <div class="main-header">
               <h1>Header</h1>
           </div>

       </header>

       <main>
           <!-- <div class="main-content">
                -->

       </main>

    <section class="lower-sec">
        <div class="left-box">

        </div>

        <div class="right-box">

        </div>

    </section>

    
   </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Why did other solutions not suite your use-case?

Comment: @ UncaughtTypeError I've tried alot of different configurations. I ve tried 
 to use an image tag in side the div, I also tried to set the background size to contain ( that left white space on both sides of containter), i tried to set the width and height of the image to the size of my container. Either way I got the image to cover the entire background but some of the image still gets cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `background-size: 100%` use

```
background-size: contain;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: I already know how to manipulate those properties on the link you gave me. None of those property-value pairs will keep the aspect ratio when enlarging the image to  cover 100% of container.

Comment: Explain then how do you want "640 x 480 image" to cover "container that is 1204 x 184". And what does it mean "see the image in its entirety". You have two options: either `cover` or `contain`.

Comment: Ok. Let say I have a div that 800px wide and 800px tall and i want to set the background to an image and the  image's original size is 500px wide and 500px tall. 
The HTML would look like this: 
<div class=center-img>

 </div>

The css would be: 

.center-img{
 width: 800px;
length: 800px;   
background-image: url(http://someimg.com/500/500/something);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Comment: This code works to make the image cover the entire container but some of the image will be cut off  since the image had to enlarge itself cover the 800x800 px of the container. So lets say it was a picture of a face , once you set the background-size to cover, the ears and top off the head would get cut off . So my question is how do I set an container's background-image's size to cover and still keep the aspect ratio where you can see the entire image.?

Comment: Why `background-size: contain;` does not work for you?

Comment: Because the image does not cover the entire background when "background-size: contain" is used. It